# PHP imap not append big mail

Tags: php, imap

I am handling `imap` in `php` via socket. Everything works perfect. I build mail swift object, then convert it to string and send to `imap` with append command, it works, I get `OK [APPENDUID 1 4497] (Success)`, but if I attach file greater than about 3kb - `imap` server responds me nothing, and the mail doesn't append! What is the problem? May be I should make append something like part by part? I mean cut mail body for several parts and make several `fwrite()`?

These are several parts of my code. But I think problem is not in the code, but in some common `imap` stuff:

```
/**
 * @param string $command
 * @param string $successPattern
 * @param bool $withCounter
 * @return false|string
 */
protected function sendCommand($command, $successPattern = '', $withCounter = true)
{
    $counter = $withCounter ? "{$this->commandHash}{$this->commandCounter} " : "";
    $successPattern = !$successPattern ? $counter . 'OK' : $successPattern;

    fwrite($this->stream, "{$counter}{$command}\r\n");
    $this->commandCounter++;

    $previousLine = '';
    $buf = '';
    $time = time();

    while ((time() - $time) < $this->timeOut) {
        $newLine = fread($this->stream, 4096);
        if(!strlen($newLine)) continue;
        $buf .= $newLine;

        file_put_contents("/LOG2.txt", $newLine, FILE_APPEND);


        if (strripos($previousLine.$newLine, $successPattern) !== FALSE){
            $this->responseContainer->setLastResponseText($buf);
            return $buf;
        }
        if (strripos($previousLine.$newLine, $this->commandHash . ($this->commandCounter - 1) . ' NO') !== FALSE
            || strripos($previousLine.$newLine, $this->commandHash . ($this->commandCounter - 1) . ' BAD') !== FALSE){
            $this->responseContainer->setLastErrorText($buf);
            return false;
        }
        $previousLine = $newLine;
    }

    var_dump(" Time out");

    $this->responseContainer->setLastErrorText("{$command} {$counter} Time out");
    return false;
}




/**
 * @param $mailString
 * @param string $folder
 * @return false|int
 */
public function append($mailString, $folder = "INBOX")
{
    if($this->sendCommand("APPEND {$folder} {".strlen($mailString)."}", "go ahead")){
        $response = $this->sendCommand($mailString, '', false);
        return $this->imapParser->parseAppendResult($response);
    }
    return false;
}




    $message = new \Swift_Message();
    $message->setSubject($mail->subject);
    $message->setFrom($mail->from);
    $message->setTo($mail->to);
    $message->addPart($mail->body, 'text/html');

    foreach($mail->files as $file){
        $attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file->getPath());
        $attachment->setFilename($file->name.".".$file->type);
        $message->attach($attachment);
    }


    $appendUid = $this->imapService->getCommander()->append($message->toString());
```

Creating stream:

```
/**
 * @param string $host
 * @param integer $port
 * @return bool
 */
protected function createStream($host, $port)
{
    //@todo proxy authentication
    if($this->stream = @stream_socket_client("ssl://{$host}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, $this->timeOut, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $this->context)) {
        stream_set_timeout($this->stream, $this->timeOut);
        return $this->stream;
    }
    $this->responseContainer->setLastErrorText("Failed connection to imap. Without proxy. " . $errstr);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note, you should be looking for '+' as the response to APPEND, not 'go ahead'; the go ahead is freeform text and can be different on different servers, or potentially not there at all.

Comment: Max thank u a lot, this is also important moment. But not solution for my problem. Do u have any ideas?

Comment: I do not.  Is it possible your stream is in text mode instead of binary mode or something else like that, or doing end of line conversion?

Comment: how do I know in which mode is my stream ? end of line conversion ? what do u mean ?

Comment: I am sure problem is exactly with size. Because even if I don't attach file, but just put big text - the same problem

Comment: Please include the code where you create `stream`.

Comment: I have included the code